# in Sankey diagram: make paths "as short as possible"?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I am interested in using Sankey diagrams, like http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/

Specifically, I am using the block that enables cycles: http://bl.ocks.org/cfergus/3956043

But, each "start-node" is drawn on the far left and each "end-node" drawn on the far right.
Ascii example:

```
|A ----> B ----> C ----> D|
|E-------------> C        | <-- starts far left
|F --------------------> D| <-- starts far left
|G ----> B ------------> H| <-- finishes far right
```

What I prefer (in my specific case) is to keep the paths as short as possible, e.g.:

```
|A ----> B ----> C ----> D|
|        E-----> C        |  <-- don't start far left
|                F ----> D|  <-- don't start far left
|G ----> B ----> H        |  <-- don't finish far right
```

Any d3js experts that know if this is easy to modify in the position calculation algorithm?

At the moment I manually move the nodes after they have been rendered.

from:

[image: original behavior]

to:

[image: desired behavior]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to achieve what you want, with a simple change in Sankey code plugin.

There is a line in function `computeNodeBreadths()` within Sankey plugin:

```
moveSinksRight(x);
```

It should be changed to:

```
moveSourcesRight(x);
```

This is illustrated in following two examples:

### Example 1

(original Sankey plugin)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3yacmtr/)

[image]

### Example 2

(with proposed change)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmfLt8w9/)

[image]

### Example 3

(with both `MoveSinksRight()` and `MoveSourcesRight()`)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62zmc22d/)

[image]

### Example 4

(without both `MoveSinksRight()` and `MoveSourcesRight()`)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9du9w07k/)

[image]

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! It seems you used the same jsfiddle for example 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach:

http://bl.ocks.org/danharr/af796d91926d254dfe99

I'm explicitly setting the x co-ordinates using graph.links[3].source.x = 200 etc.  This could be linked to a dataset rather than being hard coded I guess

Comment: Your response is appreciated, but I'm looking for what to change in the algorithm, not how to hardcode the coordinates.